# EditText, use textMultiline and Single Line at the same time?

Tags: java

Is there a way to let a user write in single and multiple lines in EditText, inputType textMultiline is for Multiline only and text for single line only, is there a way to have both?

Answer (score 0):

Multiline attribute normally allows a user to take advantage of multilines. But incase u want to achieve that, the alternative would ve to use teo edittexts. Give one the multiline attribute and the keep singleline for the other. Since single line takes precidence, you might want to hide the multiline edittext onCreate. Set a length (number of characters) at which you the user should now be switched to the multiline edittext. Save the input added at the time, hide the singleline editText then show the multiline after you have set the original text from the singleline edittext. 
I hope that helps.